# Correct idiom for allocating and deallocating resources via C interface

Tags: c++

Often C++ programs have to deal with C libraries providing free functions for allocating and freeing a resource. To simplify this example, think about two C functions like `get_resource()` and `free_resource()`.

Consider an object getting any resource at some point of its life and automatically freeing it once the object is destroyed or not fully constructed because of an error during the construction.

What is an ideal/short/simple idiom for obtaining that automatism? An idea is the following, but it makes the object not properly default-moveable. Is there anything better which does not imply freeing memory from within the destructor or checking errors in the constructor to do rollbacks?

```
struct Object {
    void* my_get_resource() { // might be called from the constructor or any other point
        return get_resource();
    }

    Object() : up(&resource, &del) { 
        resource = my_get_resource();
        /* init all the stuff, but this init might fail at _many_ points */ 
    }
    //~Object() { if (resource) free_resource(resource); } // I don't like: collides with del and is not called if my_get_resource() is called from the constructor and the init process fails for some reasons

private:
    void *resource = nullptr;
    static void del(void ** ) noexcept {
        if (*resource) { free_resource(resource); }
    }
    unique_ptr < void*, decltype(&del) > up; // RAII: almost good, sadly that makes Object not moveable properly without redefining the move constructor properly


};
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're talking about and how it differs from unique_ptr. Could you show some code explaining how you would use the class?

Comment: If your constructor has so many points of possible failure, wouldn't it be better to have your object set itself up to a bare minimum object and set everything else up through other member functions? I like to keep constructors short and sweet, I hate the idea of throwing exceptions in a constructor because it means you have to wrap every instantiation of your object in try/catch just to catch what would otherwise be a simple error code return value from another function. I do have a large C background and I'm mostly new to C++ so maybe my opinion is biased.

Comment: @dreamlax but that violates the RAII idiom... the point is that I do want exceptions being thrown whenever they happen

Comment: You're right - I don't agree with dreamlax's proposal at all. Delegating logical construction to any function other than the _actual_ constructor is a backwards step. Constructors throwing exceptions is _correct_ and writing less terse code just because you then have to bother thinking about catching exceptions is exceptionally lazy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Try adding a throw to a constructor when that object is already used by millions of other lines of code and then you'll know where I'm coming from.

Comment: @dreamlax: Those millions of lines of code, if not already exception-safe, were _themselves_ the problem, not this object. Try to code with the future in mind.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'll tell that to the team of 30 developers who have already moved onto other jobs. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @dreamlax: It sounds like you don't need to -- they have already figured out that they were playing the violin on a sinking ship, and saved their sorry souls.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes because every large company who started developing software using C++ in the 1990s knew that exceptions were the bees knees and had no performance issues whatsoever </sarcasm>

Comment: @dreamlax: This is neither the time nor the place for your religious anti-exception rhetoric.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Please see further comments [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20491/discussion-between-dreamlax-and-lightness-races-in-orbit)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You've got it wrong, I'm not anti-exception.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter doesn't meet your needs?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you want a RAII wrapper that is movable.

Then just define a move constructor and declare a protected or private copy constructor and copy assignment operator. If you don't plan on supporting current Visual C++, then you can just declare the copy constructor and copy assignment operator as deleted.

This involves checking errors in the constructor and cleaning up in the destructor, which is a odds with your requirements …

> Is there anything better which does not imply freeing memory from within the destructor or checking errors in the constructor to do rollbacks?

Simply put, the requirements are generally incompatible with your goal as indicated by the posted code.

Even if you use `unique_ptr` to do the job, the way it does it is by checking errors in the constructor and cleaning up in the destructor, directly at odds with your (extremely unrealistic) requirements.

Here's how to make a start on doing things "manually":

```
bool hopefully( bool const c ) { return c; }
bool throwX( string const& s ) { throw std::runtime_error( s ); }

class Resource
{
private:
    void* pResource;

    Resource( Resource const& );    // Add "= delete" if all compilers support it.
    Resource& operator=( Resource const& ); // Ditto.

public:
    void* theValue() const { return pResource; }  // Use problem-specific name.

    ~Resource()
    {
        if( pResource != 0 )
        {
            ::freeResource( pResource );
        }
    }

    Resource()
        : pResource( ::getResource() )
    {
        hopefully( pResource != 0 )
            || throwX( "Resource::<init>: getResource failed" );
    }

    Resource( Resource&& other )
        : pResource( other.pResource )
    {
        other.pResource = 0;
    }
};
```

You can add a move assignment operator.

And you can generalize the thing to a `Handle` class template.

---

Disclaimer: untested off-the-cuff code, not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: Interesting ... what is benefit of replacing if() with hopefully()|| ?

Comment: `hopefully` is easier to identify visually as a postcondition, than an `if`, because `if` is used for so many other purposes also. this is in the same vein as a `while` or `for` is easier to identify as a loop, than a label that is jumped to from somewhere later. so in the end it's about communicating to the reader of the code in a way that minimizes the amount of analysis that has to be applied, under assumption of trusting the author (e.g., like systematic indentation).

Comment: hm, i wrote "= 0" instead of "= delete" in the comment, and i forgot to apply some data member naming convention. fixed the former, the latter will just have to stand.